# Hook to close method on an application level

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to perform logic whenever my Android app is in the process of being closed, so to avoid duplicating the same logic on each Activity.

Similar to OnCreate() below, which is invoked whenever the app is starting, I need the close/terminate method.

```
public class Application : Android.App.Application
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `closed` - when the process is killed by the system or when app is going to background?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times your Application class will not know that it is going to shut down because usually it is just killed by the system. You can hide activity but you can't hide application since it is always there (as long as process runs). And if user (or system) decides to manually kill it  you will not get any chance to save your data since it might be time consuming. So the best way would be to call custom method in Application from your Activity's onStop() and save everything you need. And it will be a good idea to save data in background thread.

In activity class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        ((CustomApplication)getApplication()).onCloseCustom();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

In your application class

```
    public void onCloseCustom()
    {
        //do whatever you need
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of defining onCloseCustom() when it has been invoked by onStop()?

Comment: As you said - not duplicating the same logic on each Activity. I can't think of any other way your application can be notified of possible close. And as far as I know there is no way it can be notified by the system. Because user always can task-kill it and application will be closed immediately without any time for you to do your stuff.